# Problem with hyphen in URL when using fancyvrb with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, urls, fancyvrb

There seems to be a problem using a hyphen in a URL inside a fancyvrb Verbatim environment when using the hyperref package.

### The Problem

The following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\url{http://a-z.example}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

produces the following text in the output pdf:

```
http://a\unhbox\voidb@x\kern\z@\char`\discretionary{-}{}{}z.example
```

### Less than ideal workaround

The best workaround I can come up with is to replace the `url` command with
`\href{http://a%2dz.example}{http://a-z.example}`. Note the hyphen needs to be percent-encoded. This is not ideal.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Or at least a better workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In verbatim environments the `-` is made active in order to break ligatures, but `\url`, among its checks doesn't take care of this.

You can fix the behavior in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\ORIGhyper@normalise\hyper@normalise
\def\grigg@hyper@normalise{%
  \begingroup\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\-
   \lowercase{\endgroup\edef~}{\string-}\expandafter\@gobble\ORIGhyper@normalise}
\def\fixurl{\let\hyper@normalise\grigg@hyper@normalise}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},formatcom=\fixurl]
\url{http://a--z.example}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a simplistic `\detokenize` you lose the possibility of using `%` in URLs: check that

```
\url{http://a--z.example.com/%7Exyz}
```

works as expected, which wouldn't with

```
\url{\detokenize{http://a--z.example.com/%7Exyz}}
```

as suggested by Werner.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one work-around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{fancyvrb,hyperref}
\newcommand{\URL}[1]{\url{\detokenize{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\URL{http://a-z.example}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```