# Prevent ligature in verbatim text

Tags: ligatures, fancyvrb

I was looking at [Problem with hyphen in URL when using fancyvrb with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114704/problem-with-hyphen-in-url-when-using-fancyvrb-with-hyperref) but cannot quite understand the solution so cannot apply it to my problem.

I am getting an unwanted ligature in verbatim text that I colored using the work-around in [fancyvrb alternate commandchars and \textcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23091/fancyvrb-alternate-commandchars-and-textcolor) because I couldn't use brackets as the command characters.

Here is the minimal example, which shows the unwanted ligature "fi" at the beginning of the colored text:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

% -- fonts:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle} % applies to all fonts
\setmonofont[Scale=0.9,Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{TeX Gyre Cursor}

% -- custom verbatim env for typesetting code:
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor} 
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0.1,0.3}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{CodeVerbatim}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\#^\~}
\newcommand*{\fvtextcolor}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{CodeVerbatim}
    @echo #fvtextcolor^purple~^"file uses ligature"~
\end{CodeVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following PDF:

[image: PDF output of example above]

Now my question: how can I break the ligature "fi" in file when handing text over to the `\textcolor` command (via the macro `\fvtextcolor` in between)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with coloring the text, but with the fact that you're not disabling ligatures. Apparently, TeX Gyre Cursor activates `liga` by default, which seems not be a desired feature for a monospaced font. However you have also to disable the TeX ligatures for it.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

% -- fonts:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle} % applies to all fonts
% <add here your font declarations>
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\defaultfontfeatures{} % reset for mono font
\setmonofont[
  Ligatures=NoCommon,
  Scale=0.9,
  Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}
]{TeX Gyre Cursor}

% -- custom verbatim env for typesetting code:
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor} 
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.5,0.1,0.3}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{CodeVerbatim}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\#^\~}
\newcommand*{\fvtextcolor}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}} 

\begin{document}

1234567890

\begin{CodeVerbatim}
    @echo #fvtextcolor^purple~^"file uses ligature"~
\end{CodeVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: D'oh.  I guess I first noticed the ligatures in the colored text and then went off on this idea that the coloring commands are responsible.  Thanks!